# Why does the toggle navigation button show?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a bootstrap css navbar that shows a black navigation bar at the top and it is mobile responsive. Instead the toggle navigation button shows and no navbar. Why does the toggle navigation button show?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; 
    charset="utf-        8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Local Web Hosting</title>

        <!--Bootstrap core CSS-->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_4.css" type="text/css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">

        <!-- Meta Description. For Search Engines. For more about 
    <meta>    tags: w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp-->
        <meta name="description" content="A web hosting website.">

        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"
    >  </script>
        <!--[endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

    <!--HEADER
    ===================================-->
    <header class="site-header" role="banner">

        <!--NAVBAR
        ===================================-->
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse 
    navbar-fixed-top"   role="navigation">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
    data-   toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img    src="images/logo.png" alt="Web Hosting Company"></a>
                    </div><!--navbar-header-->
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hosting_plans.html">HOSTING PLANS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="features.html">FEATURES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul><!--nav-->
                    </div><!--navbar-collapse-->
                </div><!--container-->

            </div><!--navbar-->

        </div><!--navbar-wrapper-->

    </header>
```

Comment: Are you saying it wont expand on Click? You have a space here inside data-toggle >  data- toggle="collapse"

Comment: van, the black menu bar does not appear at all, instead I get just the toggle navigation button. I will see if it has to do with that space in data-toggle. Thank you in advance.

Comment: unfortunately that space in data-toggle only occurred when i posted the code here. Couldn't be that easy for me of course.

Comment: You also aren't showing Bootstrap CSS inside your head tag because it works fine.

Comment: Are you saying you attempted it and it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't accessing the Bootstrap dependencies: See working example of you code in the Snippet below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/bootstrap.css">

<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="path/to/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <!--HEADER ===================================-->
  <header class="site-header" role="banner">

    <!--NAVBAR ===================================-->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse 
    navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
              <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Web Hosting Company">
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--navbar-header-->
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="home.html">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="hosting_plans.html">HOSTING PLANS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="features.html">FEATURES</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <!--nav-->
          </div>
          <!--navbar-collapse-->
        </div>
        <!--container-->

      </div>
      <!--navbar-->

    </div>
    <!--navbar-wrapper-->

  </header>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: interesting, I notice in your link you dont add .js after bootstrap.min

Comment: I see what I did, I believe I linked js files but not css files.

Comment: There are two versions of these files (and of most libraries in general): a Minfied version (bootstrap.min.css/bootstrap.min.js) and a non-minified (bootstrap.css/bootstrap.js)

Comment: Yes, like I said in my second comment, there is no CSS (and no jQuery either which you need placed before Bootstrap.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

### **Best Approach That You Make It With Your Skill Like**

**Java Script Code**

```
$("#btn_toggle").click(function(e) {
       $(this).toggleClass('on');
       $(".main_nav").slideToggle("normal");

      });
```

**Css Code**

```
    .btn_toggle{position:absolute;width:30px;height:30px;right:5px;top:3px;display:none;cursor:pointer;border:none;z-index:2000;-webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;background:none;}
    .btn_toggle span{position:absolute;background-color:#4e4751;height:5px;border-radius:2px;display:block;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%}
    .btn_toggle span::before,.btn_toggle span::after{position:absolute;content:"";left:0;width:100%;height:5px;border-radius:2px;background-color:#4e4751;display:block;
    transition:all 0.3s;backface-visibility:hidden; 
    }
    .btn_toggle span::before{bottom:8px;right:0;}
    .btn_toggle span::after{bottom:16px;left:0;}
    .btn_toggle.on span{background-color:transparent;}
    .btn_toggle.on span::before{transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-1px, 2px)!important;
   }
    .btn_toggle.on span::after{transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, 2px)!important;
    }
```

**Html Code**

```
<button class="btn_toggle" id="btn_toggle" title="Menu"><span></span></button>
                <ul class="main_nav">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                </ul>
```